# Highlight Table row after clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

How can I highlight the table selected row? I am generating table row with JavaScript ES6 map function, with IDs and Names in the cells. So I need two thing.

1. I want to change the color of the row which I have click and
2. I need to get the  ID of that particular row in a function?

My code looks something like this

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    ${users? users.map((user) => html`
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 104px;">user.id</td>
        <td style="width: 175px;">
            user.name
        </td>

    </tr>
    `) : ''}
</table>
```

Comment: attach an onclick on row (<tr>) and use access that row using $(this) inside that onClick function and add whatever css you want using css() method. add the id as a data attribute inside <tr> and it will be available inside the function.

Comment: don't attach the onclick on row, it won't work if he creates them with javascript. Attach the onclick to the whole table and delegate the event to all rows. Then you also have the ability to get every attribute (and child, ...) of the row you just clicked.

Comment: Can I have an exmple @cloned?

Comment: with jquery: `$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() { console.log(this) }` inside the function this referrs to the element clicked, so you will get the tr in the console. with this.className (or any other valid JS function/...) you can get every attribute or child element from the TR.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the ID of that particular row in a function?

You can bind `on-click` handler on `tr` with anonymous function to pass `user` to your function.

```
<tr on-click='${() => this.selectUser(user)}'>
```

In this way in `selectUser` function will receive `user` as parameter.

> I want to change the color of the row which I have click

You can manually manipulate the DOM by using some functions such as `querySelector` and `setAttribute` but I would recommend you to keep that state as a property.

In `selectUser` function

```
selectUser (user) {
  this.selectedUser = user
}
```

then bind `selected` attribute on `tr`

```
<tr selected?='${user === selectedUser}' on-click='${() => this.selectUser(user)}'>
```

Live demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7d9lbv?file=index.js)